# How can I choose the left alignment size of a graphics

Tags: includegraphics

I'm using \includegraphics to display a pdf on my latex paper but I want it to be positioned at the leftmost position (\begin{flushleft} isn't enough), how can I do that?

Comment: leftmost position of what? a graphic is positioned using the same logic as a letter, so flushleft would put it at the leftmost edge of the text block.  To make if go further to the left you can use `\hspace*{-1cm}`

Comment: You might try preceding it by `\noindent`, although `flushleft` should take care of that.

Comment: The real question is if you want something to the right of the image.  I suspect what you are looking for is wrapfig.